# Marker is not relative to Google map when mapping in React

Tags: reactjs, database, google-maps, react-redux, mapping

When I am displaying a marker on Google Map in a simple way (no database, no mapping), I get a decent marker which is attached to a certain adress (street, buildind, etc.) But when I take data from database and use map function to get my data, markers move wrong (they are relatvie not to map but to screen in general). Is mapping happening every second and is rerendering my marker?

First marker (outside mapping) works fine. Those inside mapping function doesn't.

```
    // Works good
    <Marker
      lat={55.690954}
      lng={21.156816}
    />
    /////////////////////


    // Does not work good
    {data.map(item => (
      <div>
        <Marker
          lat={55.690954}
          lng={21.156816}
          /* lng={item.location.coordinates[0]}
          lat={item.location.coordinates[1]} */
        />
      </div>
    ))}
    /////////////////////
```

Video of problem:

[image]

Comment: I'd be guessing that the wrapping `div` might be a problem.

Comment: Thank you, it is absolutely the case!